# How to print out a pointer value from array?

Tags: c, pointers

I know this is basic stuff, but I'm having one particular problem with this.

I'm implementing a simple shell program, and the exit function needs to pass on the exit value if one is passed on.  Therefore, `exit 45` should return 45 as a value, but nothing to be printed*.

The commands are passed to a function parser in a `char **arglist` array.  Since `exit 45` is two args, I need to print out the last arg.

However,my debug statement `printf((int)&arglist[1])` returns a value of 163393752, which is just slightly off from the passed in value.  When I changed `printf` to `puts`, the correct value was printed out, but `exit()` requires an integer, not a pointer.

Using this example how can I get 45 from the pointer array?

*according to the professor, quoting his phrasing verbatim.

Comment: This sounds like homework...is it?

Comment: Its for a school project.  Basically the last bit I need to complete to satisfy all the requirements

Comment: Homework or not, I think some code needs to be shown.  Why describe what's going on when a few lines of code will make so we don't have to guess at the details?  And copy/paste is your friend.  By the way, it sounds like you need to convert the string "45" to an `int`.

Comment: The relevant code is already there in `printf((int)&arglist[0]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the `atoi` function in `stdlib.h` (or write your own equivalent if you're not allowed to use the library).

Comment: I had completely forgotten that function!  Thats what I needed, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` needs a format string; check out the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

`(int)&arglist[1]` should be `arglist[1]`, and it's a `char *` not an `int`

Answer (score 0):

Is that printf argument passing the address instead of the value? Should it be *arglist[1]?
I'm a little rusty in c pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `&arglist[1]` is the same as `&(*(arglist+1)`, which actually prints the *address in memory* of arglist[1]. If you want to print the value at this point, just print `arglist[1]` - `printf()` doesn't usually need the &.

Comment: when you need to pass a pointer `*value` to a function that requires an actual value, `&value` is the correct operation.  So for a pointer array, the inverse is true?

Comment: Ah, the value of a pointer is usually with * yes. But array[1] actually does dereferencing for you. Thus, the _value_ at arglist[1] is 42, which you get by calling arglist[1]. The & operator is the address-of operator.
In any case, your item at `arglist[1]` is a string (i.e. char*), so you want to `printf("%s\n", arglist[1])` - or, like others have suggested, use `atoi()` to convert it to an integer

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do is like this:

```
./your_program # run your_program
ret_val=$? # gets exit status and stores into $ret_val
./other_program $ret_val # pass exit status of your_program to other_program as a argument
```

However, it's not a right way to pass value from one program to another. Because only lower 8 bit of exit status of a program is used, see: http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit .

You can pass value from one program to another program use `exit` **iff** your purpose is to pass the **exit status**(8bit number) not the **exit value**(an integer).

The typical way to pass a value to other program is print the value: eg:

your program:

```
printf("%d", value);
exit(0);
```

in shell:

```
value=`./your_program` # run your program and store output into 'value'
./other_program $value
```

in other_program: use `strtol` (`atoi` is deprecated) to convert string to integer:

```
int value = stdtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
```